# Decision Table example for a CAD system user interface

Tags: c++, coding-style

I want to put the user interface for a simple CAD system in a decision table. But i am concerned about
how to put these stuff in a table.

First, there is a current mode (CurMode) which can be:
Move, Rotate, Delete

Next, there are mouse actions like this:

OnLButtonDown
OnLButtonUp
OnRButtonDown
OnRButtonUp
OnMButtonDown 
OnMButtonUp
OnMouseMove

Maybe there is an addition test for an object under the current mouse cursor like this
ObjectUnderMouse (true/False)

With these and other parameters i want to decide for following rules:

If Mode is Delete and an object is under the mouse and the OnLButtonDown is pressed, delete the Object.

If MButtonUp   is pressed (MouseWheel), zoom +
If MButtonDown is pressed (MouseWheel), zoom -

if Mode is Move and an object is under the mouse and the OnLButtonDown is pressed, put the object in a buffer.
If Mode is Move and OnLButtonDown and object in Buffer and OnMouseMove acts, move the object

...... and so on.

Do you get the scenario ?

I googled a lot and saw very simple DT´s but how do this as a good start for a propably big CAD System with hundreds of
parameters, states, modes and UI- Actions.

What is the best design for a decision table to act for such a CAD system ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You did not specify what framework you will use to develop your program, if any, but QT has a nice API for this: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/statemachine-api.html

Answer (score 1):

Statestep (http://statestep.com) might be what you're looking for. The examples given on the website are for user interfaces, and its use for a very large system (decision table with rules covering millions of possibilities) is described. There's code generation for C.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply. I will take a closer look at statestep (we do not use QT). But in general i have problems to decide which part of my cad system is a condition, an action, a condition alternatives etc. to define a decision table like wiki. [Wiki Decision Table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_table)

Comment: this is not an answer to your question, please use comments for this

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar decision process to implement and here is what I came up with. Probably can be rewritten to be more beautiful, but that's another topic!

And you can also align booleans in the if statements to be always on the same columns to look even more like a table.

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
EditToolMode *EditTool::decideToolMode()
{   
    bool const isLongPress = (m_lastReleaseTime - m_lastPressTime) > sm_longPressThreshold;
    bool const isMouseMoved = (m_startCoords.get() - m_currentCoords.get()).norm() > sm_movedMouseThreshold;
    bool const isOnPoint = m_closestPoint.is_initialized() && (m_closestPointDistance2d < sm_onPointThreshold);
    bool const isOnEdge = m_selectedPolyline.is_initialized();
    bool const isOngoingSelection = !m_ongoingSelection.empty();
    bool const isEndEdit = m_editChronology == END_EDIT;
    bool const isOnOngoingSelection = isPointOnOngoingSelection(m_ongoingSelection, m_closestPoint);

    if (isOngoingSelection && isOnPoint && isOnOngoingSelection)
    {
        return new ...;
    }

    if (isOngoingSelection && !isMouseMoved && !isOnEdge)
    {
        return new ...;
    }

    if (!isMouseMoved && !isOnEdge && isEndEdit)
    {
        return new ...;
    }

    if (!isMouseMoved && isOnPoint && isLongPress)
    {
        return new ...;
    }

    if (!isMouseMoved && isOnEdge && isLongPress)
    {
        return new ...;
    }

    if (isMouseMoved)
    {
        return new ...;
    }

    return nullptr;
}
```